# Thread safety for boost ublas matrix

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, synchronization, mutex

I need to synchronize access to a container of boost::numeric::ublas::matrix type amongst my main thread and a couple of worker threads. Do I need to explicitly code for synchronization using locks? Or is the ublas matrix container 'thread safe', which I think means that it uses locks internally to grant mutually exclusive access thereby preventing race conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do your own explicit synchronisation.  Mutices are a good choice for that.

Comment: Why is that? Isnt boost matrix thread safe? Or do I need to do synchronization inspite of it being thread safe?

Comment: @user3670482: Huh?  First, there is no synchronisation inside ublas.  Second, there is no synchronisation in most containers.  If you don't synchronise yourself, there will be no synchronisation.